# What is the default encoding used in System.Net.Mail.Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString in c#?

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

You can use `System.Net.Mail.Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString` without specifying the encoding like so `Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(content, name)`, what encoding will be used to encode content string in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the same as your machine, for example, I live in Germany, my encoding is Windows-1252. I use to had problems with this because the UTF 8 were not working.
By the way, you should use MimeKit, amazing and free library to handle emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144618(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1), it's either ASCII or UTF-8:

> If the content is in ASCII format then the character encoding is set to ASCII. For all other formats, the character encoding is set to utf-8. The default media type is plain text.
>
> If the content is not in ASCII format and the encoding is null, utf-8 encoding is used.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/Attachment.cs,ef94439e5abc1a40 backs that up

Comment: if I do it like so `string content = "some hardcoded string"; Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(content, name)` what encoding will be used?

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych it depends on what is in there.